# s3slider jquery

Tags: jquery

sorry guys but why would s3slider plugin for jquery throw this error when I followed everything to the letter. here is the error

```
$("#s3slider").s3slider is not a function
```

here is the code for which the s3slider works on:

```
<div id="homepics">
<div id="s3slider">
                <ul id="sliderContent">
                    <li class="s3sliderImage">
                        <img src="<?="$base$images";?>/gallery/cleaningup.jpg" alt="" />
```

**Cleaning Up**
And it's not just her Act
                        
                        
                            /gallery/fetching-water.jpg" alt="" />

**Getting Water to Drink**
Should it be this hard?
                        
                        
                            /gallery/getting-water" alt="" />
  **Waiting in Line**
And Patiently too.
                        
                            /gallery/grabbing-lunch.jpg" alt="" />

**Grabbing Lunch**
Guess what is for Lunch?
                        
                        
                            /gallery/ironclad-future.jpg" alt="" />
  **An IronClad Future?**
Doing his bit to make that happen.

```
                    <li class="s3sliderImage">
                        <img src="<?="$base$images";?>/gallery/kidz.jpg" alt="" />
```

**Kids**
Doing their Bit of Household chores.

```
                    <li class="s3sliderImage">
                        <img src="<?="$base$images";?>/gallery/marketplace.jpg" alt="" />
```

**At the Market Place**
Business of Buying and Selling.

```
                    <li class="s3sliderImage">
                        <img src="<?="$base$images";?>/gallery/necessaryservice.jpg" alt="" />
```

**Providing a Necessary Service**
Adding Value the Best he can

```
                    <li class="s3sliderImage">
                        <img src="<?="$base$images";?>/gallery/onthe-job.jpg" alt="" />
```

**On The Job**
Vital Refreshment on the Job.

```
                </ul>
            </div>
```

Comment: I linked directly to google jquery lib thinking mine was the problem and but still nothing only now I am getting this error:

uncaught exception: [Exception... "Could not convert JavaScript argument arg 0"  nsresult: "0x80570009 (NS_ERROR_XPC_BAD_CONVERT_JS)"  location: "JS frame :: http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js :: anonymous :: line 12"  data: no]

Line 0

Answer (score 0):

What does your script block look like?

If it literally says this:

$("#s3slider").s3slider

try changing it to:

$("#s3slider").s3slider();

Comment: script block says this: $('#s3slider').s3Slider({timeout: 4000}); this is about the strangest error ever. what do you think

Comment: well I checked and i had to a. update firefox and then go over the code again and make a lot of additions. I wanted to customize it but messed with it pretty good. MY BAD guys sorry.